# Source less iframe bug firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, widget

I'm using a src less iframe to develop a javascript widget to protect my css from the parent page.

It's perfectly working in chrome/safari. However in firefox I can see the content is added during few milliseconds and then the iframe becomes empty.

If I inspect html I see empty head and empty body, however if I inspect innerHtml through the console I can see that It has the right content...

I'm sorry I can't give you code as it's hard to pull out the relevant parts : I can tell you I access the iframe with jquery contents() and then find body or find head.

Any idea plz ?

I Managed to make an example : http://jsbin.com/arenat/2/edit#javascript,html,live
Just some code pull out to show the issue : working on chrome no in firefox (10.0.1). Hope it's enough.

---

Comment: Adding some sample code, or link to page would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the frame to the DOM, it starts loading about:blank asynchronously.  Then you modify the DOM in the iframe ... and then the asynchronous load completes and replaces the document you modified.

I suggest either using an onload handler on the iframe to do your manipulation after the about:blank has finished loading or using document.open() and document.close() to force cancellation of the async load.

Comment: Yep working great with the handler, and it's better than a timeout I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's working with a timeout :

http://jsbin.com/arenat/9/edit

Comment: Agreed, sometimes timeout fix these issues.